# how can I apply mockK when viewModel uses pref in init block?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit4, kotlin-coroutines

Here's my ViewModel class.

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val serviceRepository: ServiceRepository,
    private val userPrefRepository: UserPreferencesRepository,
    override val preferencesRepository: PreferencesRepository,
) : BaseViewModel() {

    private val _menuList = mutableResultState<MenuData>(ResultState.UnInitialize)
    val menuListState: StateFlow<ResultState<MenuData>>
        get() = _menuList.asStateFlow()

    var isCancelButtonVisible: Boolean = false

    init {
        isCancelButtonVisible = getCancelButtonVisibility()
    }

    // I used this to test private method.
    @VisibleForTesting(otherwise = PRIVATE)
    fun getCancelButtonVisibility(): Boolean = preferencesRepository.cancelButtonVisibility

    fun fetchMenus() = viewModelScope.launch{
        serviceRepository.fetchMenus()
            .onState {
                _menuList.value = it
            }
    }
}
```

FYI, I never have written test codes. And at the moment, I'd like to test `fetchMenus()` method. So, maybe I need to check `menuListState` is set after calling `fetchMenus()`.

(I will use turbine library to check flow data)

```kotlin
    // TODO: must initialize getCancelButtonVisibility first and then need to set something to test MainViewModel and fetchMenus() method.
    @Test
    fun fetchMenus_success_returnMenuList() = runTest {
        // given
        coEvery { mainViewModel.getCancelButtonVisibility()} returns true

        // then
        mainViewModel.menuListState.test {
            assertNotNull(awaitItem())
        }
    }
```

I get error this error after running the test:

```
no answer found for: PreferencesRepository(#2).getCancelButtonVisibility()
io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for: PreferencesRepository(#2).getCancelButtonVisibility()
```

Comment: I ran into a similar problem. Unfortunately, there is no solution implemented by MockK, yet. Here are the related issues: https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/437
https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/261

Comment: @fabiankuenzer you also need to define the return for the preference value. In my case, `coEvery { preferenceRepository.cancelButtonVisibility } return SOMETHING`. I was wrong to use viewModel in coEvery, since it's ViewModel's UnitTest and I mocked the repositories.

Comment: If you're not particularly interested in the outcome of a certain function and you just want to verify that it was executed at a certain point you can also use the @RelaxedMockK annotation.

Comment: @fabiankuenzer yes, you can return default value. But most of the time, I think I need fixed value and It was for getting certain value from the preferenceRepository.